# How can I add formatting lines to a TMemo in Delphi

Tags: delphi, line, tmemo

Just tried to find this on the net to no avail.

All I want to do is add a solid line between each row in a tmemo in Delphi
but for the life of me I cant find out how.

Should be just a property - underline text or not...

Anyone been through this and found a way?

Many thanks!

Tried searching the net and also looked at all Tmemo properties, tlines properties...

Comment: Hi think Tmemo is a plain text and does not support styling such as adding a solid line. Please try with TRichEdit. But still if you wish to use Tmemo, then you can try using the character (-) after each row and should be okay, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Harish, Is there an option to put formatting lines between each data line in a richmemo?  What Im after is to have a line between lines of data to delineate,

Comment: For future reference - TMemo is a wrapper around a multi-line TEdit, which means it is the same exact thing as the standard Windows application Notepad. If you can't do it in Notepad, you can't do it in a TMemo.

Comment: Thanks Ken, its a tqrmemo in quickreport that im trying to demarcate between data lines..  maybe i can change color between lines.  Cheers for that.

Comment: For lines in QuickReport, use a `TQRShape` and set it's `.Shape` to `qrsHorLine`.

Comment: When I need to, I do it old-school: set a monospace font, and use `#13#10` + `------`  Simple and readable.

Comment: Hey thanks all!